# Silverlight can´t access FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, authentication

I have a ASP.Net Login

```
    if (Membership.ValidateUser("User", "Password"))
    {
       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("Testuser", false);
       Response.Redirect("TestingAuthNewTestPage.aspx");
    }
```

And this is working fine. I get to the silverlight page.

Then if I want to logout I try to use FormsAuthentication.SignOut(), but in my silverlight app, I cant access FormsAuthentication?

The only way it works is if I call:

```
    WebContext.Current.Authentication.Logout();
```

Is that a good way of logging out? or how can i access the FormsAuthentication class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should Clear the Authentication cookies too.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); 
Session.Abandon(); //Clears Sessions

//This modification will Clear cookies
HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

//Redirect to login page
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

Comment: The problem is that in my silverlight code I cant access the FormsAuthentication class. Is that because I use ASP login and therefore dont have a authentication domain service?

Comment: ASP login do have a authentication service. there would be minor issues like adding namespaces though :P check if you imported using security namespace :)

Comment: I tried adding the security namespace, but it still says that it cannot resolve symbol "SignOut". Is it because it´s a silverlight project and not a asp project?

Comment: I think i got it... I cant call FormsAuthentication from silverlight because it´s part of the System.Web, and I cant use that in silverlight. Instead i have to have a button thats call a ASP page, which have a Logout method, and that method is going to have FormsAuthentication.SignOut() etc.. social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/7c9d11f2-7cee-4f8f-a1dc-06e1c8f03062